# How to tune an Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, replace, database-performance, cross-join

The table temp has the columns "word" and "sentence". Below code checks, if the sentence has any words from the word column. If the word exists, the word will be replaced with a URL (contains the word itself and its id). The code works fine for about 1-10 rows. The table has about 50k records. It consumes the whole of the temp space. How can I review and fine-tune the query?

Requirement: There are 50k words and sentence. The requirement is to replace the words in the sentences with a URL (contains the word and its id) if any of the words exist in the word column. While looking for the words, the search has to be case insensitive. Also, we need to retain the same case in the sentence while replacing with the URL.

```
Create table temp(
  id       NUMBER,
  word     VARCHAR2(1000),
  Sentence VARCHAR2(2000)
);

insert into temp
SELECT 1,'automation testing', 'automtestingation TeStInG TEST is popular kind of testing' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'testing','manual testing' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 2,'test', 'test' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'manual testing','this is an old method of testing' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'punctuation','automation testing,manual testing,punctuation,automanual testing-testing' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'B-number analysis','B-number analysis table' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6,'B-number analysis table','testing B-number analysis' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7,'Not Matched','testing testing testing' FROM DUAL
```

SQL Types:

```
CREATE TYPE stringlist IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
/
CREATE TYPE intlist IS TABLE OF NUMBER(20,0);
/
```

PLSQL Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION replace_words(
  word_list IN  stringlist,
  id_list   IN  intlist,
  sentence  IN  temp.sentence%TYPE
) RETURN temp.sentence%TYPE
IS
  p_sentence       temp.sentence%TYPE := UPPER( sentence );
  p_pos            PLS_INTEGER := 1;
  p_min_word_index PLS_INTEGER;
  p_word_index     PLS_INTEGER;
  p_start          PLS_INTEGER;
  p_index          PLS_INTEGER;
  o_sentence       temp.sentence%TYPE;
BEGIN
  LOOP
    p_min_word_index := NULL;
    p_index          := NULL;
    FOR i IN 1 .. word_list.COUNT LOOP
      p_word_index := p_pos;
      LOOP
        p_word_index := INSTR( p_sentence, word_list(i), p_word_index );
        EXIT WHEN p_word_index = 0;
        IF (   p_word_index  > 1
           AND REGEXP_LIKE( SUBSTR( p_sentence, p_word_index - 1, 1 ), '\w' )
           )
           OR  REGEXP_LIKE( SUBSTR( p_sentence, p_word_index + LENGTH( word_list(i) ), 1 ), '\w' )
        THEN
           p_word_index := p_word_index + 1;
           CONTINUE;
        END IF;
        IF p_min_word_index IS NULL OR p_word_index < p_min_word_index THEN
          p_min_word_index := p_word_index;
          p_index := i;
        END IF;
        EXIT;
      END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
    IF p_index IS NULL THEN
      o_sentence := o_sentence || SUBSTR( sentence, p_pos );
      EXIT;
    ELSE
      o_sentence := o_sentence
                    || SUBSTR( sentence, p_pos, p_min_word_index - p_pos )
                    || 'http://localhost/'
                    || id_list(p_index)
                    || '/<u>'
                    || SUBSTR( sentence, p_min_word_index, LENGTH( word_list( p_index ) ) )
                    || '</u>';
      p_pos := p_min_word_index + LENGTH( word_list( p_index ) );
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN o_sentence;
END;
/
```

MERGE

```
MERGE INTO temp dst
USING (
  WITH lists ( word_list, id_list ) AS (
    SELECT CAST(
             COLLECT(
               UPPER( word )
               ORDER BY LENGTH( word ) DESC, UPPER( word ) ASC, ROWNUM
             )
             AS stringlist
           ),
           CAST(
             COLLECT(
               id
               ORDER BY LENGTH( word ) DESC, UPPER( word ) ASC, ROWNUM
             )
             AS intlist
           )
    FROM   temp
  )
  SELECT t.ROWID rid,
         replace_words(
           word_list,
           id_list,
           sentence
         ) AS replaced_sentence
  FROM   temp t
         CROSS JOIN lists
) src
ON ( dst.ROWID = src.RID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET sentence = src.replaced_sentence;
```

Comment: PLease show any errors, and output form an explain plan.  Thanks

Comment: Added the explain plan. I got ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
and ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace TEMP.

Comment: I told you before, separate the words in one table and the sentences in another. Your current input structure makes no sense and makes solutions more difficult.

Comment: You need to "review and fine-tune" your requirement. You said in other questions that the search for the "word" is case-insensitive, but you want the URL to retain the case of the "word" as it was in the sentence. You did not repeat that part of the requirement here. Your requirement is hard enough in itself: it doesn't help to have a stupid input structure and an incomplete requirement.

Comment: Hi Stew, apologies if it wasn't clear. There are 50k words and sentence. Do you think it would be a feasible solution to create a table with just words of different cases? For e.g. E commerce (the forms that we need to create in a new table would be E commerce, E Commerce, E COMMERCE, e commerce). The requirement is to replace the words in the sentences with a URL (contains the word and its id) if any of the words exist in the word column. While looking for the words, the search has to be case insensitive. Also we need to retain the same case in the sentence while replacing with the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I separate words (with ids) from sentences, and I put words in lowercase because you want a case insensitive search anyway. If I find two matches at the same position in the sentence, I choose the longer one. If there are **overlaps** ('manual testing' and 'testing strategy'), I always choose the "word" that comes first in the sentence.

Best regards,
Stew Ashton

```
SQL> Create table temp(
  2    id       NUMBER,
  3    word     VARCHAR2(1000),
  4    Sentence VARCHAR2(2000)
  5  );

SQL> insert into temp
  2  SELECT 1,'automation testing', 'automtestingation TeStInG TEST is popular kind of testing' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 2,'testing','manual testing' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4  select 2,'test', 'test' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 3,'manual testing','this is an old method of testing' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 4,'punctuation','automation Testing,manual tEsting,punctuation,automanual teSting-tesTing' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  7  SELECT 5,'B-number analysis','B-number analysis table' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  8  SELECT 6,'B-number analysis table','testing B-number analysis' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  9  SELECT 7,'Not Matched','Testing tEsting teSting' FROM DUAL;

SQL> create table sentences as select sentence from temp;

SQL> create table words cache as
  2  select length(word) word_length,
  3    min(id) id,
  4    lower(word) word
  5  from temp
  6  group by length(word), lower(word);

SQL> insert into sentences
  2  select listagg(word, ',') within group(order by word)
  3  from words;

SQL> insert into sentences values('Nothing matches here');

SQL> commit;

SQL> declare
  2    cursor cur_sentences is 
  3      select rowid rid, sentence from sentences s
  4      where exists (
  5        select null from words
  6        where instr(lower(s.sentence), word) > 0
  7      )
  8      for update;
  9    type tt_sentences is table of cur_sentences%rowtype;
 10    lt_sentences tt_sentences;
 11    lt_sentences_new tt_sentences;
 12  
 13    function change_sentence(p_sentence in sentences.sentence%type)
 14    return sentences.sentence%type is
 15      cursor cur_words(cp_sentence in sentences.sentence%type) is
 16        with recurse (pos, word_length, id, word) as (
 17          select regexp_instr(cp_sentence, '(^|\W)('||word||')(\W|$)', 1, 1, 0, 'i', 2),
 18            word_length, id, word
 19          from words
 20          where regexp_instr(cp_sentence, '(^|\W)('||word||')(\W|$)', 1, 1, 0, 'i', 2) > 0
 21          union all
 22          select regexp_instr(cp_sentence, '(^|\W)('||word||')(\W|$)', pos+1, 1, 0, 'i', 2),
 23            word_length, id, word
 24          from recurse
 25          where regexp_instr(cp_sentence, '(^|\W)('||word||')(\W|$)', pos+1, 1, 0, 'i', 2) > 0
 26        )
 27        select pos, word_length, id, word,
 28          substr(cp_sentence, pos, length(word)) new_word
 29        from recurse
 30        order by pos, word_length desc;
 31      type tt_words is table of cur_words%rowtype;
 32      lt_words tt_words;
 33      lt_words_kept tt_words:= new tt_words();
 34      l_pos number := 0;
 35      l_sentence sentences.sentence%type := p_sentence;
 36    begin
 37      open cur_words(p_sentence);
 38      fetch cur_words bulk collect into lt_words;
 39      for i in 1..lt_words.count loop
 40        if l_pos < lt_words(i).pos then
 41          l_pos := lt_words(i).pos + lt_words(i).word_length;
 42          lt_words_kept.extend;
 43          lt_words_kept(lt_words_kept.count) := lt_words(i);
 44        end if;
 45      end loop;
 46      close cur_words;
 47      for i in reverse 1..lt_words_kept.count loop
 48        l_sentence := regexp_replace(
 49          l_sentence,
 50          lt_words_kept(i).new_word,
 51          'http://localhost/'||lt_words_kept(i).id||'/<u>'||lt_words_kept(i).new_word||'</u>',
 52          lt_words_kept(i).pos,
 53          1
 54        );
 55      end loop;
 56      return l_sentence;
 57    exception when others then
 58      close cur_words;
 59      raise;
 60    end change_sentence;
 61  
 62  begin
 63    open cur_sentences;
 64    loop
 65      fetch cur_sentences bulk collect into lt_sentences limit 100;
 66      exit when lt_sentences.count = 0;
 67      lt_sentences_new := new tt_sentences();
 68      lt_sentences_new.extend(lt_sentences.count);
 69      for i in 1..lt_sentences.count loop
 70        lt_sentences_new(i).sentence := change_sentence(lt_sentences(i).sentence);
 71      end loop;
 72      forall i in 1..lt_sentences.count
 73        update sentences set sentence = lt_sentences_new(i).sentence where rowid = lt_sentences(i).rid;
 74      exit when cur_sentences%notfound;
 75    end loop;
 76    close cur_sentences;
 77  exception when others then
 78    if cur_sentences%isopen then
 79      close cur_sentences;
 80      raise;
 81    end if;
 82  end;
 83  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from sentences order by 1;

SENTENCE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Nothing matches here
automtestingation http://localhost/2/<u>TeStInG</u> http://localhost/2/<u>TEST</u> is popular kind of http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u>
http://localhost/1/<u>automation Testing</u>,http://localhost/3/<u>manual tEsting</u>,http://localhost/4/<u>punctuation</u>,automanual http://localhost/2/<u>teSting</u>-http://localhost/2/<u>tesTing</u>
http://localhost/1/<u>automation testing</u>,http://localhost/5/<u>b-number analysis</u>,http://localhost/6/<u>b-number analysis table</u>,http://localhost/3/<u>manual testing</u>,http://localhost/7/<u>not matched</u>,http://localhost/4/<u>punctuation</u>,http://localhost/2/<u>test</u>,http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u>
http://localhost/2/<u>Testing</u> http://localhost/2/<u>tEsting</u> http://localhost/2/<u>teSting</u>
http://localhost/2/<u>test</u>
http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u> http://localhost/5/<u>B-number analysis</u>
http://localhost/3/<u>manual testing</u>
http://localhost/6/<u>B-number analysis table</u>
this is an old method of http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Stew. I will run this on the original table and let you know. Is it feasible to add the id column from the temp table to sentences table? As the sentence column in the temp table has to be updated with the replaced text.

Comment: "Is it feasible to add the id column from the temp table to sentences table?" Sure, go ahead.

Comment: Unfortunately, insert into sentences select listagg(word, ',') within group(order by word) from words; this gives "ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long"  as we have close to 50k words, Stew.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the solution, it's just additional test data, as is the following insert. Did you also insert IDs 1 through 7 into your table? Did you also drop the real table so you could run my CREATE TABLE statement? I hope not.

Comment: I did not drop any tables :) You are right. It works for the test data,Stew. If id = 1 was automtestingation www.google.com/TeStInG TEST is popular kind of testing, we should not replace the words which are already a part of the URL. Like the word TeStInG is part of www.google.com/TeStInG. The outcome is supposed to be automtestingation www.google.com/TeStInG http://localhost/2/<u>TEST</u> is popular kind of http://localhost/2/<u>testing</u> . Can we handle this scenario?

Comment: Also, due to not curated data we get ORA-12725: unmatched parentheses in regular expression.

Comment: I have spent too much time on this already. You keep adding new bits to the requirement. You need to pay someone to come help you define precisely the requirement, create representative test data, solve the problem and provide support. You clearly cannot take over maintenance of the solution. Good luck!

Comment: I agree you have spent time on this, Stew. I really appreciate it. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Stew, I am trying to make use of the same code. I need your help to fix just one thing. If a word is found as part of another word, it's getting replaced. For e.g. two-way. we have a word way. How do we find the exact term to replace? I tried to using this (^|\W)('||word||')(\W|$) but didn't work.

Comment: In the case of "way two-way https:://way.com" we have to replace just the word way in the beginning. The word can be anywhere in the sentence. Would that be possible to handle?